# How to implement an LSTM RNN with multiple input features

Tags: time-series, lstm, multiclass-classification, rnn

EDIT: Now I didn't convert to list.

I am training LSTM for multiple time-series in an array which has a structure: 450x801. There are 450 time series with each of 801 timesteps / time series. The labels are classes with assigned integer from 1 to 6, so the dimension of the label is 450x1. This is my implmentation:

This is my code:

```
def readData():
labels = pd.read_csv('label.csv', header = None)
labels = labels.values
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header = None)
return data, labels

data, labels = readData()

data_train, data_test, labels_train, labels_test = train_test_split(data, labels)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=32, input_shape = (450,801,1)))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now I got this error:

```
Error when checking input: expected lstm_26_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (450, 801)
```

Any idea how to solve it?

For instance I can try to reshape:

```
data_train = np.reshape(data_train, (data_train.shape[0], 1, data_train.shape[1]))
data_test = np.reshape(data_test, (data_test.shape[0], 1, data_test.shape[1]))
```

And now the error is:

**raise ValueError('Must pass 2-d input')
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input**

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. You are trying a classification task with a multivariate LSTM model that takes 450 variables as input?

Comment: @Leevo, yes, that's correct. Wouldn't it work?

Comment: It can work, but the computational effort is going to be huge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spot an error in your code. The input sequence for `LSTM()` layers must follow this schema:

> ( Number of observations ,  Number of Timesteps  ,  Number of input
>   series )

When you specify the `input_shape` argument you drop the number of observations. Therefore it becomes:

```
model = Sequential([

    LSTM(32, input_shape = (801, 450)), 

    Dense(6, activation='softmax')    
])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

That's why you had an error about the number of input dimensions.

One final observations: 450 input features on 801 timesteps is *a lot*. Consider using some dimensionality reduction technique, because that's going to be very hard computationally speaking.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking to either use TimeDistributed or maybe even employ Convolutional LSTM. Do you think ConvLSTM would be easier to compute? These are basically time-series from time-domain signal that can be converted into time-frequency-domain (2D-array) by using STFT.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know your problem well enough to say if it's going to work. Conv2D layers are meant to receive 2D input matrices (such as image pixels), is that your case?

Comment: Hi, I could convert my time-series into time-frequency domain, thus creating an image which is called "spectrogram". Is that enough explanation? It's normal in signal processing to convert 1D vector array time-series into 2D matrix of time-frequency domain.

Comment: As far as I know, yes it could work. Please consider that a Conv + Recurrent model is going to be computationally expensive. If you can train it it's worth give it a try though.

Answer (score 0):

It is becouse you convert your data to list `data = data.values.tolist()` But model input expects an array but not a list of arrays. So you need to convert your input list to the array.